# jQuery auto scroll div to div and back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll

I found this code for autoscroll a page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
var myInterval = false;
myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 5000);

function AutoScroll() {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    iScroll = iScroll + 500;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: iScroll
    }, 1000);
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (iScroll == 0) {
        myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 5000);
    }
    if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

        clearInterval(myInterval);

        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "index.php"; },3000)  

    }
});
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

My page looks like this:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
```

My goal is to autoscroll from div to div after 20 seconds en after the last div back to top.

My Question is:

1. How to make it work scrolling from div to div?
2. I use window.location.href = "index.php" for refreshing the page en start over again. Is there a different way to achieve the same without a refresh? So go back to the top div and refresh the content of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To scroll from div to div, you could define an array of the selectors for each div. Then in your `AutoScroll` function, get the element at the current index, get the offset from the top of the page for that element, and scroll to that. Then increment the index value.
2. To scroll to the top of the page, set the index back to 0 when there are no more elements to scroll to

Something like this should work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myInterval = false;
            var index = 0;
            var elements = ["#div1","#div2","#div3","#div4","#div5"];
            myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 5000);

            function AutoScroll() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(elements[index]).offset().top
                }, 1000);

                if(index < (elements.length - 1)){
                    index++;
                } else {
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the last part: index = 0; to setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); },15000) and got exactly I was was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3gb5uLgs/

1. I added this function

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

2: You can use `location.reload();`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Option 1, unfortunately the div is in this case not to the top of the page. The second option works perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ScrollTop function, and use it when you reach bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var myInterval = false;
                myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 5000);

                function AutoScroll() {
                    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    iScroll = iScroll + 500;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: iScroll
                    }, 1000);
                }

                //The function scroll to 0 position.
                function scrollTop()
                {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 1000);
                }
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (iScroll == 0) {
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                        myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 5000);
                    }
                    if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                        //Instead refresh, I just scrolled to top.
                        setTimeout(scrollTop,5000)
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, I used location.reload();  for renewing/refreshing the page

Comment: It is smoother without refreshing the page. Reload is an option if you insist on refreshing the page each time you get to the bottom.